# jQuery and Java applets

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, applet

I'm working on a project where we're using a Java applet for part of the UI (a map, specifically), but building the rest of the UI around the applet in HTML/JavaScript, communicating with the applet through LiveConnect/NPAPI. A little bizarre, I know, but let's presume that setup is not under discussion. I started out planning on using jQuery as my JavaScript framework, but I've run into two issues.

**Issue the first:**

Selecting the applet doesn't provide access to the applet's methods.

Java:

```
public class MyApplet extends JApplet {
  // ...
  public String foo() { return "foo!"; }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var applet = $("#applet-id");
alert(applet.foo());
```

Running the above JavaScript results in

```
$("#applet-id").foo is not a function
```

This is in contrast to Prototype, where the analogous code does work:

```
var applet = $("applet-id");
alert(applet.foo());
```

So...where'd the applet methods go?

**Issue the second:**

There's a known problem with jQuery and applets in Firefox 2: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/bug_applet/jquery_applet_bug.htm

It's a long shot, but does anybody know of a workaround? I suspect this problem isn't fixable, which will mean switching to Prototype.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the first issue, how about trying

```
alert( $("#applet-id")[0].foo() );
```

For the second issue here is a [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/c67483e58caacbfd) with a possible workaround.

Quoting the workaround

> ```
> // Prevent memory leaks in IE
> // And  prevent errors on refresh with events  like mouseover in other  browsers
> // Window isn't included so as not to unbind existing unload events
> jQuery(window).bind("unload",
> function() {
>         jQuery("*").add(document).unbind();
> });
> ```

change that code to:

> ```
> // Window isn't included so as not to unbind existing unload events
> jQuery(window).bind("unload",
> function() {
>         jQuery("*:not('applet, object')").add(document).unbind();
> });
> ```