# Calling Javascript functions from a Java Applet

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

I have a Java Applet in a HTML page.
I need to have the applet call a certain Javascript function to notify the HTML page of certain events.

The way I call the JavaScript function currently is:

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:window.notifyEvent("+msisdn+")"));
```

I define the actual function within the HTML code but when the applet actually calls it I get 
the `Uncaught ReferenceError: notifyEvent is not defined` error.

Where do I need to define the javascript function for the applet to be able to call it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you must use [JSObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html).  It's been around for a long time, although I hear there can be differences between browsers still.  So if you need to support many browsers I'd suggest checking across your supported set once you see it work in one.

[Bridge between the Java applet and the text input controls on the web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014561/bridge-between-the-java-applet-and-the-text-input-controls-on-the-web-page)

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html