# Is it posible to run JS function from URL in java applet.

Tags: java, javascript, svg

I'm new to programming. I'm developing java applet to view some spatial data that I get from MapViewer serwer. I get SVG image url with some other javascript function that may be used for example to zoom Map. Is there any way to use that function in my applet?

I know that it is possible when use JSObject, but I run my applet in netBeans so I'am not able to create JSObject using JSObject.getWindow(this).

I wonder is possible to run js function from file?

Comment: You should take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684105/calling-javascript-functions-from-a-java-applet

Comment: I saw that before, but they are also about applet on web page