# calling javascript function from within java applet - Firefox vs. IE

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, applet

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-15" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var foo;

function test(s)
{
    foo = s;
    alert(foo);
}

window.onload = function ()
{
    foo = 'init';
    document.getElementById('foo').doit();
    alert(foo);
}
</script>
<body>
<applet id="foo" code="TestApplet.class"
    archive="TestApplet.jar" width="0" height="0"></applet>
</body></html>
```

Java applet code:

```
public void doit ()
{
    try {
        getAppletContext().showDocument(
            new URL("javascript:test(\"foobar\")"));    
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I call this HTML page :

- **In IE (8)** I get: First popup ("foobar"), second popup ("foobar").
- **In Firefox (19.2, 30.0)** I get: First popup ("foobar"), second popup ("init").

Can anybody explain why? Obviously, *`foo` is written by the applet only temporarily*.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This topic and answers could be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014561/bridge-between-the-java-applet-and-the-text-input-controls-on-the-web-page